# ReactJS: Google BILLING_UNAVAILABLE using In App Purchase 2 (Capacitor)

Tags: reactjs, in-app-purchase, capacitor

I have followed the instructions and am getting errors when clicking the button to subscribe (product is a subscription, built in ReactJS using Capacitor)

```
startServiceConnection() -> Failed: BILLING_UNAVAILABLE: Billing service unavailable on device.
D/CordovaPurchase: init() -> Failed: BILLING_UNAVAILABLE: Billing service unavailable on device.
D/CordovaPurchase: callError({code:6777001, msg:"Setup failed. BILLING_UNAVAILABLE: Billing service unavailable on device.")
```

Everything is more or less the same as the IOS version and have added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

To the AndroidManifest.xml file.

I have deployed to Open Testing and when clicking on the button on my phone nothing appears, so something obviously broken...

I have the subscriptions setup under Monetize in the Play Store. So I don't understand why this is not working. Within the fovea dashboard I don't see anything Google related to Products (even though I have followed all instructions on that page, as well as sent a test notification from Google)

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the problem when debugging on emulator, while debugging on a real device it was gone, and I had a different error which helped me to find the root cause of my problem eventually.